# Discord.py commands always says as existing command, even when it's completely random

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a Discord bot in discord.py that just responds to commands, like when you type =!firewall it says Hello! Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = ('')

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='=!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def chickennuggets(ctx):
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

However, when I try to run the command with =!firewall in Discord, the console returns this:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pixdoet/Code/python/firewall/bottest.py", line 19, in on_message
    async def chickennuggets(ctx):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1257, in decorator
    self.add_command(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1143, in add_command
    raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command chickennuggets is already an existing command or alias.
```

As it is pretty obvious, chickennuggets is not a default command, nor a command used by any other libraries in Python. I have searched the Internet for this but with no avail. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're referencing your command `chickennuggets` with a different name in your post, which tells me that you're using an alias for the command in your code. However, you haven't shown the alias or how you're defining it. You're indentation in your code is also incorrect. Try this out:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='=!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases = ['firewall'])
async def chickennuggets(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

TOKEN = ('') # insert your token here
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Also, please don't leak your bot's token to any public forum, because others can run their code through your bot using your bot's token. Now, you'll have to go to your application in Discord's Developer Portal and generate a new token. This will null your previous token so that nobody can use it to run their code on your bot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but client is actually used, in client.user

Comment: Oops, overlooked that.

Comment: Instead of using `client.user` use `bot.user`. You're running the bot instance, not the client. Also why defining both? There's no point of doing that